# How to read the data from sql (pyodbc) in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to read data from my SQL database using PyODBC and Scrapy. How do I do this? This is what I have so far:

```py
import scrapy
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_sql_query("select top 10 * from Organization where countryid = 13 and revenue='unknown'",con)

class ZoominfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zoominfo'

    def start_requests(self):
        #con = database_connect():
        for index in table.index:
            company = table["Name"][index].strip()
            url = f"https://www.google.com.ua/search?q={company + '+link+overview'}"
            req = scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_google_results, cb_kwargs={"company": company})
            req.meta['proxy'] = None
            yield req
```

Comment: Do you gt an error? What’s the current behavior and what did you expect instead?

Comment: I don't even idea of where to write the database credentials.

Comment: Maybe you should then rethink your question. [Create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), probably without any Scrapy code, as it does not seem relevant.